# Calculating duration from a timestamp column by groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
   dttm           runid
9/7/2023 00:10  1694020173
9/7/2023 00:10  1694020173
9/7/2023 00:10  1694020173
9/7/2023 00:10  1694020173
9/7/2023 00:10  1694020173
9/29/2023 20:31 1695908276
9/29/2023 20:31 1695908276
9/29/2023 20:31 1695908276
9/29/2023 20:31 1695908276
9/29/2023 20:31 1695908276
```

The `dttm` column is of `datatime64[ns]` datatype.
I want to add a column that shows the duration of subsequent rows in the `dttm` column subtracting from the very first row in the same column grouped by `runid`

I resorted to using a helper column defining the start time for each `runid` like so:

```
df['_Start_Time']=df.groupby('runid')['dttm'].transform('min')
df['Duration']=((df['dttm']-df['_Start_Time']).dt.total_seconds())
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this without using an extra column?
Perhaps using the `apply()` method?

Comment: just straightforward: `df['Duration']=(df['dttm']-df.groupby('ruinid')['dttm'].transform('min')).dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: @QuangHoang Can you put your suggestions as an answer so I can award you the answer? 
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
df["Duration"] = df.groupby("runid")["dttm"].apply(
    lambda x: (x - x.min()).dt.total_seconds()
)
```

Comment: don't `.apply`, it is quite a bit slower than `.transform('min')`.

Answer (score 1):

try this approach

```
def calculate_duration(group):
    start_time = group.iloc[0]['dttm']
    group['Duration'] = (group['dttm'] - start_time).dt.total_seconds()
    return group

df['Duration'] = df.groupby('runid', group_keys=False).apply(calculate_duration)['Duration']
```